# Intellisense at odds with compiler: "A namespace with this name does not exist" vs "not a class or struct name"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, intellisense, atl

I have an ATL project with a class implementing an interface (generated using the "Implement Interface" shortcut in VS). The automatically generated stdafx.h contains:

```
#import "C:\path\to\base.dll" raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, no_namespace, named_guids, auto_search
```

My class (`CPLUGIN`) implementing the interface (`IBase::IBaseClient`):

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CPLUGIN :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CPLUGIN, &CLSID_PLUGIN>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IPLUGIN, &IID_IPLUGIN, &LIBID_MyLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
    public IBaseClient {
 ...
```

As-is, intellisense complains that IBaseClient is "not a class or struct name", but it compiles fine.

If I add `using namespace IBase` or fully qualify the base class name (`IBase::IBaseClient`), then the intellisense errors go away, but the compiler says "`IBase`: a namespace with this name does not exist" and fails to compile.

How can I make both IntelliSense and the compiler happy?

Comment: Making intellisense happy should not be a high priority. Your best chance is to update or wait for the next update for microsoft to fix it (and hope they didn't break something else).

Comment: Ah, so it's just an intellisense bug that I should write-off?

Comment: Intellisense is known to occasionally put red squigglies under perfectly fine code. You can try rightclicking on your solution and select "rescan solution" to force intellisense to think harder before adding squigglies, but if they persist just ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

User nwp is right: a context menu option "rescan solution" does the trick. One thing to notice: this option belongs in a Project context menu, not a Solution context menu. At least it is true for a Visual Studio 2015 on my Windows 10 computer.

Comment: Also true in VS 2019.